# Splitting objects into containers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Apologies if I'm posting in the wrong place.  This is not a homework question, but rather a question from someone wanting to know if there's a more efficient way to do this than the traditional IT style of an if/else loop in a script.

Here's what I need to solve :

- You may use any number of containers subject to constraints of min. 1, max. 10000.
- In each of those containers, you may place min. 100, max. unlimited objects
- We set an "ideal" number of objects per container of X
- We need to determine the "realistic" number of objects per container in order to fit the maximum constraint defined in the first point above (i.e X number of objects per container is all well and good, but if it takes us over max. containers, then that's not much use).

Hope the above makes some sense !

Edit to add clarification (see comment to Ross below)... in summary I'm looking for a smart way to say "Hey, I can't fit 2097152 into max. 10000 buckets at an "ideal" 100 each.. how much do I need to increase the count per bucket".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified your objective.  If you have $N$ objects and put $X$ of them per container, you need $\lceil \frac NX \rceil$ containers.  Similarly, if you want no more than $10000$ containers, you need to put at least $\lceil \frac N{10000} \rceil$ objects per container.  Since I can put as many objects in a container as I want, it seems the optimum would just be to put all the objects in one container.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Ross... Aah... sorry !    All in one container is not optimal due to transmission bandwidth constraints. For the rest, since its an IT problem, I'll try explaining it that way :  Let's say I hardcode a bucket size of 100MB, but I have 2TB (2097152MB) of data... that would leave me with excess data bay the time I hit 10000 buckets.  Hence I'm looking for a smart way to say "Hey, I can't fit 2097152 into max. 10000 buckets at 100 each.. how much do I need to increase the count per bucket".

Comment: The value $\lceil \frac N{10000} \rceil$ shows how much should go into each bucket.  If you want the increase over your current bucket, subtract that from the requirement.

Comment: Think I might have been staring at code too long ! Thanks !  I'll make sure I come back with a more challenging question next time ! ;-)